# How to take word class in ntlk?

Tags: python, python-2.7, nlp, nltk

I want to get word class like: objective, adjective, verb - how can I do it?

```
from nltk import corpus

a = ['What', 'is', 'your', 'first', 'and', 'last', 'name', '.']
```

Question is quite simple but I do not know nltk?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pos_tag` function from [`nltk.tag`](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tag.html) module :

```
>>> from nltk.tag import pos_tag
>>> a = ['What', 'is', 'your', 'first', 'and', 'last', 'name', '.']
>>> pos_tUse NLTK’s currently recommended part of speech tagger to tag the given list of tokens.ag(a) 
[('What', 'WP'), ('is', 'VBZ'), ('your', 'PRP$'), ('first', 'JJ'), ('and', 'CC'), ('last', 'JJ'), ('name', 'NN'), ('.', '.')]
```

> `pos_tag`
> Use NLTK’s currently recommended part of speech tagger to tag the given list of tokens.

Also you can use `pos_tag_sents` for tag the given list of sentences.

Answer (score 1):

NLTK provides the function post_tag for your:

```
import nltk
text = nltk.word_tokenize("What is your first and last name.")
pos_tags = nltk.pos_tag(text)
```

You can check the meaning of the pos_tag results here:
https://www.ling.upenn.edu/courses/Fall_2003/ling001/penn_treebank_pos.html